# Outputting to Convertto-html Cmdlet Powershell

Tags: forms, powershell

Evening everyone, 
I've spent a while having a play on google learning how to create a basic form with powershell. Currently I'm having a problem coming to grips with how to get this basic form to output to a html file at the click of a button I have managed to get it to work with the services ie -

> Get-Service | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File "Location"

However i'm wanting to input data on my form and then once the submit button is pressed, it puts the data into a table and then outputs it to the html file.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "BasicForm"
$Form.Width = 800
$Form.AutoScroll = $True

#VRN label
$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,75)
$objLabel.Text = "Num:"
$objLabel.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel)

#VRN Textbox
$objtextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$objtextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,75)
$objtextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,150)
$Form.Controls.Add($objtextbox)

#Title by Label
$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,75)
$objLabel.Text = "Title:"
$objLabel.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel)

#Title by Dropdownbox
$objtitlelist = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$objtitlelist.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,75)
$objtitlelist.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,50)
$objtitlelist.Items.Add("Mr")
$objtitlelist.Items.Add("Mrs")
$objtitlelist.Items.Add("Ms")
$Form.Controls.Add($objtitlelist)

#Title by Textbox
$objtextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$objtextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,75)
$objtextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,150)
$Form.Controls.Add($objtextbox)

#Title by Label
$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,125)
$objLabel.Text = "Title:"
$objLabel.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel)

#Title by Dropdownbox
$objtitlelist = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$objtitlelist.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,125)
$objtitlelist.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,50)
$objtitlelist.Items.Add("Mr")
$objtitlelist.Items.Add("Mrs")
$objtitlelist.Items.Add("Ms")

$Form.Controls.Add($objtitlelist)

#Title by Textbox
$objtextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$objtextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,125)
$objtextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,150)
$Form.Controls.Add($objtextbox)

#Date label
$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,125)
$objLabel.Text = "Date:"
$objLabel.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel)

#Date Textbox
$objtextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$objtextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,125)
$objtextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,150)
$Form.Controls.Add($objtextbox)

#Add Button docs
$Buttondocs = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Buttondocs.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(175,35)
$Buttondocs.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
$Buttondocs.Text = "Documentation"
$Form.Controls.Add($Buttondocs)

#Add Button docs event
$Buttondocs.Add_Click({Button_Click})
Function Button_Click()
{
Invoke-Item "C:\Users\Michael\Documents\PowershellProjects\EIMI\*.txt"
}

#Add Button html
$Buttonhtml = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Buttonhtml.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35,35)
$Buttonhtml.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
$Buttonhtml.Text = "Submit Form"
$Form.Controls.Add($Buttonhtml)

#Add Button html event 
$Buttonhtml.Add_Click({Button_Click})
Function Button_Click()
{
ConvertTo-Html | Out-File "C:\Users\Michael\Documents\PowershellProjects\EIMI\index.html"
}

#Add Question 1
$Question1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Question1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,175)
$Question1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,50)
$Question1.Text = "Random Form Question."
$Form.Controls.Add($Question1)

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

The documentation invoke-item section is another problem altogether but I beleive I have found a solution to that one. Unless someone has a simple method. Apologise if this is just trivial nonsense but I'm learning from playing with things. Any suggestions on good authors would be greatly appreciated, or even tips on how to improve this in general.

Thanks Mike.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for answering specific coding questons.  You might want to check out one of the other StackExchange sites such as Superuser or Codereview.

Comment: @Paradox This doesn't seem to be a good question for Code Review. Please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users). And I can't really imagine what this question has to do with SuperUser...

Comment: the basic thing missing from the script is a function to extract the values entered in the form and assembled in an object that would then be passed to the `ConvertTo-Html` function. an example you could try to get the idea of what you need to do would be `objtextbox.text | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File "C:\Users\Michael\Documents\PowershellProjects\EIMI\index.html"` presuming you are looking at exporting the entered values of the form. I don't use windows forms ever but I think this may lead you down the correct path.

Comment: My bad, you're right about Superuser.  This question is not suitable under any of the SE sites at the moment.  However, I feel that it could fit in on code review after some serious editing as the question does involve working code.  If you believe otherwise, please do let me know so that I can clear up any confusion.